# Using variable in mysql_query WHERE statement not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use a variable within a query WHERE statement, but it shows 0 results. If I directly hard code the text instead of using the variable, it works. The variable is pulling from a `$_GET`, and if I echo that variable, it is showing the correct text.

Here's my code:

```
$Domain = $_GET['Domain'];
$result = mysql_query(SELECT Code, Title, Domain, Status FROM tablename WHERE Domain="$Domain" ORDER BY Code');
```

If I swap out `$Domain` for direct text, like `ABC`, it works. I have tried swapping out the quotes and single quotes throughout the statement, removing the quotes around $Domain, concatenating the statement separately.... all yield erros or the same result.

And as stated, if I `echo $Domain`, it shows `ABC` (or whatever it's supposed to show), so I know it's pulling correctly from the `$_GET`.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 1. Missing quotation marks. 2. SQL injection vulnerability ahead; [please read here for tips on how to prevent it](http://bobby-tables.com). 3. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this,

```
mysql_query("SELECT Code, Title, Domain, Status FROM tablename WHERE Domain='$Domain' ORDER BY Code");
```

Place the query within `"..."`, and put `'...'` around your variable `$Domain`.

Comment: A note: you should not be using `mysql_* functions`, instead you should upgrade to `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: Still better to do `'" . $Domain . "'`. Newbies get very confused and think `'$_GET['Domain']'` would also work (it doesn't work ofc).

Comment: I have switched out the quotes and it always threw several errors. So of course I do it again now and it works. :-\  Thanks for the help - not sure why this didn't work before!

Answer (score 1):

You missed a quote just before `SELECT`

```
$result = mysql_query( SELECT Code, Title, Domain, Status FROM tablename WHERE Domain="$Domain" ORDER BY Code');
                      ^ right there
```

change it to:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT Code, Title, Domain, Status FROM tablename WHERE Domain="$Domain" ORDER BY Code');
```

***However,*** you would be better off changing it to: *(and see notes about prepared statements below)*

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Code, Title, Domain, Status FROM tablename WHERE Domain='$Domain' ORDER BY Code");
```

or `Domain='".$Domain."'` if using `Domain='$Domain'` fails.

> *"If I swap out `$Domain` for direct text, like `ABC`, it works."*

**A:** That's because the string that is being passed through most likely contains characters that need escaping. I.e.: Colons, slashes `http://` and dots `http://www.example.com` etc.

Since you were using `ABC` as a simple string with nothing else to hamper the execution of SQL, it passed.

Using [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) would have helped, including [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

I.e.: `$Domain = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Domain']);`

---

### Important note

***Do use*** [**`mysqli_` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), they're so much better to work with, ***and safer.*** Because as it stands, your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).

Using error reporting is a must also:

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php**

and
`or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` which will signal errors found in code.

Comment: I missed the quote above, but not in my actual code. As per another comment, i swapped the quotes again and somehow it worked this time (but not the other times i tried to do it). Thanks!

Comment: @sleepywan You're welcome. The types of quotes and how you quote variables and queries, is a factor. Prepared statements would take care of that a lot easier.

Comment: @sleepywan I've added some additional information in my answer for you to read, as to why using `ABC` worked but not the variable. Reload the answer.

Comment: @sleepywan You're welcome. I hope my explanation as to why it was failing has helped you understand the errors.